# Obtengo error al listar propiedades

Tags: mysql

tengo el siguiente método para guardar propiedades en un sistema de inmobiliaria:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `USP_Guardar_propiedades`(IN nOpcion INT,
    nCodigo_pr INT,
    nombre VARCHAR (255),
    dc VARCHAR (50),
    dl longtext,
    situacion VARCHAR (255),
    condicion VARCHAR (255),
    archivo VARCHAR (255),
    ubicacion VARCHAR(255),
        ciudad VARCHAR (255),
    barrio VARCHAR (255),
    tipo_propiedad VARCHAR (255),
    banos int,
        dormitorios int,
    dueño int,
    web char(2)
    )
BEGIN

IF nOpcion = 1 THEN
    -- Nuevo Registro        
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO propiedades (
    nombre,estado,descripcion_corta,descripcion_larga,situacion_actual,banos,dormitorios,condicion_venta,img_principal,ubicacion,ciudad,barrio,tipo_propiedad,id_dueño,publicar
    )
VALUES
    (nombre,'1' ,dc,dl,situacion,banos,dormitorios,condicion,"",ubicacion,ciudad,barrio,tipo_propiedad,dueño, web);
    

END;


ELSE
    -- Actualizar registro        
BEGIN
    UPDATE propiedades
SET nombre=nombre,
 descripcion_corta = dc,
 descripcion_larga = dl,
 situacion = situacion,
 banos =banos,
 dormitorios = dormitorios,
 ubicacion=ubicacion,
 ciudad=ciudad,barrio=barrio,id_dueño=dueño
WHERE
    id_propiedad = nCodigo_pr;


END;


END
IF;


END
```

Pero al entrar al datagridview de mi formulario obtengo:
**System.Data.ConstraintException: 'No se pudieron habilitar las restricciones. Una o varias filas contienen valores que infringen las restricciones NON-NULL, UNIQUE o FOREIGN-KEY.'**

No tengo definidas claves foráneas en mi base de datos(trabajo comparando los id nomas), ocurre solo con los propiedades:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `USP_Listado_propiedades`(IN cTexto varchar(255))
begin 
IF (cTexto!="") THEN  
select a.id_propiedad,    
   a.nombre,
  a.descripcion_corta,a.descripcion_larga,
  a.situacion_actual,    
  a.banos,a.dormitorios,a.condicion_venta,a.ubicacion,a.ciudad,a.barrio,a.tipo_propiedad  
 
 from propiedades          a  
 where a.estado=1 and   (      
 upper(    
    trim(a.nombre)  
 ) like CONCAT('%',upper(trim(cTexto collate utf8_spanish2_ci)),'%')  )OR (      
 upper(    
    trim(a.ubicacion)  
 ) like CONCAT('%',upper(trim(cTexto collate utf8_spanish2_ci)),'%')  
)
order by a.id_propiedad  limit 1000;
ELSE
select a.id_propiedad,    
   a.nombre,
  a.descripcion_corta,a.descripcion_larga,
  a.situacion_actual,    
  a.banos,a.dormitorios,a.condicion_venta,a.ubicacion,a.ciudad,a.barrio,a.tipo_propiedad

 from propiedades          a       
  where a.estado=1  order by a.id_propiedad  limit 1000;
END IF;
end
```

No tengo filas con valores null ni vacios, por eso no entiendo el error lo unico que tengo es el id_dueño debe coincidir con el codigo_pr de la tabla propietarios(pero no esta como foreign key), y el sp funciona perfecto en la base de datos.

Comment: Hola. Por favor,.comparte el `CREATE TABLE` de **`propiedades`**. Y, si como dices, no defines ninguna restricción en dicha tabla, el problema podría venir de algun `TRIGGER` que dispara el INSERT y/o el UPDATE.